# How to gracefully handle Kafka publication failure, via spring cloud stream, triggered from REST api

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-transactions, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a scenario that several messages have to be published via a trigger from REST api in service layer.

This service also has db operations (insert, update). The requirement here is if there’s a network problem causing issue that publisher can’t publish, or when kafka broker is not available, we want to rollback everything including the database, and inform user via API response that it fails.

**Q1**: Is it possible to achieve the requirement by enable Kafka transactional?

From what I understand by default in the same transaction database will be committed first then following by kafka, but what I am not sure is if there’s any case when kafka fails to commit we will completely lose the message and database won’t rollback.

I did some test on a simple spring boot project with the following setups:

1. Spring boot version: 2.5.2
2. Spring cloud version: 2020.0.3
3. org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge is used

I weren’t able to reproduce the scenario of losing messages. What I have tried is to put a delay at the end of transactional method to put a pause before transaction begins to commit and shutdown kafka broker (in local environment), I can see that the publisher will try to reach out to kafka and will eventually fail with timeout causing the rollback of the whole transaction including db.

```
    @Transactional
    public PurchaseOrder createOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("Starting create order");

        var result = purchaseOrderRepository.save(purchaseOrder);
        log.info("purchase order is created: {}", result.getId());

        var kafkaResult = streamBridge.send("toStream-out-0", purchaseOrder);
        log.info("Kafka send result {}", kafkaResult);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return result;
    }
```

This is the timeout from publisher side.
`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(true)`

**Q2**: If this requirement can’t be achieved by kafka transactional, is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initTransactions` on producer side :

https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-exactly-once

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m actually using spring cloud stream with kafka transactional enabled at the producer side in the sample. 

My question (Q1) is more about if this is safe enough to prevent the message lost in any failure scenario. And (Q2) if there is any other better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @Peeranut well than you can use retry mechanism for that 

https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/15/kafka-consumer-error-handling-retry-and-recovery/

Comment: Hi the link you sent is more on the consumer initiate error handling. In this context as I explained the trigger of publisher is from rest api. As for retrying, to a certain point it will fail if broker is not reachable for example. 

If that event happen, my first thought is to rollback everything. And Kafka transaction seems to be doing the job as I get the timeout from kafka when committing the transaction as in initial post and it rolled back. The question is if this is bullet proof or is there any other better solution in the context where message can’t be lost with spring cloud stream.